# cx_freeze and openssl error after compilation

Tags: python, openssl, cx-freeze, pyopenssl

I have a PySide program that uses pyOpenSSL to do a certificate check, I compile it with Cx_Freeze and whenever I try to open it after compiling it I get the following error:

[image]

I'm using pyOpenSSL 0.14, Cx_Freeze 4.3.3 and PySide 1.2.2.

Why am I getting the exception?

Comment: Ive always had issues with cxFreeze on windows ... I just use pyinstaller to build an exe (although to be fair you may still run into issues with openssl) ..... if I want an installer I will use pyinstaller to create my installed stuff then package it with innosetup

Comment: But my program had no problem before I added pyOpenSSL, so It's not _specifically_ a cx_Freeze issue.

Comment: Related: ALT+PRNTSCRN captures the window with focus, so you don't have to trim an image of the desktop.

Comment: @jww I was using a virtual machine, so it didn't quite work properly because of my shortcuts on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposting from the mailing list: Adding `cryptography` to packages in the setup.py file fixed this issue. The cryptography package loads some submodules using `__import__()`, which prevents cx_Freeze from automatically finding what modules are needed. Putting it in `packages` makes cx_Freeze copy all submodules.